# Populate Database From a Text File asp.net Mvc Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a Asp.net Mvc project and I'm trying to use Code first(I'm beginner).
I used migrations to create a Database, table etc. 
I want to populate the database (a table from it) with a text file and then sort and basically do some work with that table . It's a simple text file full of words.
In the migration i understood it's the place to write the code but can't manage to find how to use a text file to seed the database.

```
    public partial class PopulateTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

        Sql("INSERT INTO Words (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'word1' )");
    }
```

I know you can insert like here and delete etc, but is is possible to do it from a text file?

And second question: how can i use then the database to do some work on that table ex: sort the words in the table and write them in a label,textbox etc?
Thanks

Comment: Check here please https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: Thanks!From what i saw it's only about seeding data generally.It is helpfull but i would like to find out if i can seed the database from a text file .txt

Answer (score 1):

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\FilePath.sql"));

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, the file has words and some of them have " ' " (the quote character),
Incorrect syntax near 'aardvark'.
Unknown object type 'created' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
Incorrect syntax near 'deleterious'.
Incorrect syntax near 'endanger'.
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'igloo'.
The name "printability" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: I tried adding them with sql directly and it added all of them, but with code first i'm just getting a long error

Comment: Give me an example of the query in the text file

Comment: The text file is a list of words: ex: aardvark
aardvarks
aardvark's
aardwolf
ab
abaca
aback
abacus
abacuses
abaft
abalone
abalones
abalone's
abandon
abandoned
abandonee
abandoner
abandoning
abandonment
abandons
abase
abased
abasement
abasements
abases etc and i used the command to read it: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Gremania\Desktop\AnagramsN\again\Anagram\Content\brit-a-z.txt"));